# is there a way to invoke nano <filename> so it will fail if <filename> doesn't exist?

Tags: nano

I am creating a set of instructions like

```
nano /home/username/preexisting-file.txt
```

where, of course, we tell people to replace "username" with their own username.  But people still forget, and they copy and paste the command without changing

Comment: This doesn't answer your question directly, but why not tell them to `nano ~/preexisting-file.txt`?  That way, they don't have to change **anything** about the command.

Comment: If the directory `username` does not exist, `nano` should not create it. Alternatively, create a file `/home/username/preexisting-file.txt` with content `warning!!! replace username with your own name` and `chmod 444` that file.

Comment: 1. `[[ -f file ]] && nano file || echo "file doesn't exist!"`, but don't know if you want to add too much code. 2. Teach the people to use tab completion instead of copy pasting, which I think is the best option.

Comment: @JimL. well the home directory was a bad example; what I mean is that there are other places where they're supposed to replace their username, like src/testpipeline/username-code.java (which is pre-made by the tutorial program) and they forget to replace it.

Comment: You might consider training them to `nano src/testpipeline/${USER}-code.java`

Comment: add a wrapper around nano to do various tests before running the actual command. If tests fails, give an error message reminding them what they should have done